# Passing props to vue instance from .blade.php file using createElement and render function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-props

---

EDIT: Some more information:

I have a main-page.blade.php file, with this:

```
//main-page.blade.php where vue instance will mount

<div id="main-page" class=" bg-uoi-green">
    <main-page :data=['one'] ></main-page>
</div>
```

There is also a main.js file importing the app.js file of Vue, where the instance for main-page is defined ( I have installed vue-loader and template compiler).

The app.js for Vue is:

```
//app.js of Vue

import Vue from 'vue'
import './assets/tailwind.css'


//
// import MainPage from './components/MainPage.vue'
// const mainpage_inst=new Vue({
//   el: '#main-page',
//   components: {
//     MainPage,
//   },
//   props: ['data'],
// });


  Vue.config.productionTip = false



    





export default {
 

  mainpage_inst,


}
```

Compiling for my application was giving me exactly what was needed. But then, if I try to also check the Vue directory using vue client, I get an empty page; this was to be expected since the vue-cli does not use the full-build. But even when I changed

```
// import Vue from 'vue'
```

to

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js';
```

I was getting a blank page when visiting localhost:8080 from vue-cli.

I was able to fix it by using the render function of vue. So now, the instance became:

```
import MainPage from './components/MainPage.vue'
  // Main page instance
  const mainpage_inst = new Vue({
    render: h => h(MainPage),
  }).$mount('#main-page')
```

*But, no matter how I try to pass props as before, my main application cannot see them, in contrast to the previous writing where it was able, but vue-cli was producing a blank page.*

For clarification: I have a Vue-app inside a different app that is loaded with all the required( I think) modules to read and compile .vue files. But I would also like to be able to run the Vue-app using the vue-cli.

So, is my main-app missing a module and is not able to get the props? Or is there some other way to make 'understand'?

Thanks again.

---

In the past, I was using the following code to create the application instance :

```
// const mainpage_inst=new Vue({
//   el: '#main-page',
//   components: {
//     MainPage,
//   },
//   props: ['data'],
// });
```

and I was calling the MainPage component from a .blade.php file by passing the props:

```
<main-page :data=" {{ $data_to_send_as_props }}" > </main-page>
```

Now I want to use the following code:

```
import MainPage from './components/MainPage.vue'
// Main page instance
const mainpage_inst = new Vue({
  render: h => h(MainPage),
}).$mount('#main-page')
```

but if I try to define the props as before, the application does not recognizes them. What is the correct way to write the above excerpt of code, so that props will be passed ? *In other words, how and were should I add the props definition on the instance above (note also that I should implement also the change mentioned in the answer of Daniel)*

---

Edit:

This is a simplified version of the MainPage.vue component

```
<template>


        <div class="  h-screen w-screen md:text-2xl text:2xl " id="main-page ">
            <div class=" flex flex-shrink text-4xl md:text-9xl font-bold md:ml-20 md:my-5 md:py-0 py-10 title">
                A Title
            </div>

            <div class="flex flex-col flex-grow h-1/3 ">

                <div v-for="(item,index) in slicedArray " v-bind:key="item.id" >
            
                    <div class=" flex flex-col md:flex-row md:flex-grow w-full hover:bg-uoi-green px-10 border-black border-2  transition duration-500 cursor-pointer ease-in-out bg-opacity-70 transform hover:bg-opacity-95"  :class="{active: isActive === item.id}">
                        <div class=" date-font h-full w-1/6 md:flex-grow px-2 py-4"> {{item.date}} &#8212;  </div>
                        <div class=" h-full w-2/3 md:flex-grow px-2 py-4 text-left"> {{item.title}} </div>
                        <div class=" date-font h-full w-1/6 md:flex-grow px-2 py-4 text-right"> {{item.exp_date}} </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class=" bg-white py-10 px-20" v-if="isActive === item.id"> 
                        <div > {{item.text}} </div>
                        <div class='file'> <a href=''> Σχετικό αρχείο  </a> 
                            <!-- <img src="../assets/curved-up-arrow-.png"  class="arrow"/>  -->
                        </div>  
                    </div>




                </div>

                

            </div>

        </div>









</template>

<script>


export default {
    name:'MainPage',
    props: ['data'],
    

    data(){
    
        return{
        
        isActive: null,
        newsToShow: 3,
        totalnews: 0,
        
        array:[],
        slicedArray:[],

        
        }
    },



    mounted(){

        this.newsToShow=3;
        this.array=this.data;
        this.totalnews = this.array.length;
        // console.log(this.array)
        
        this.slicedArray=this.array.slice(0,this.newsToShow)


        
        
    },
}   
    
</script>

<style scoped>


</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the breaking changes in Vue 3 was that the Global Vue API was changed to use an application instance. To create a vue app, use the `createApp` function to create the instance.

[a-new-global-api-createapp](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/global-api.html#a-new-global-api-createapp)

The render function (`h`) is not provided by the render function, so you need to import it. [docs](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/render-function-api.html#_3-x-syntax)

so your instantiation should look something like this:

```js
import { h, createApp } from 'vue'
import MainPage from './components/MainPage.vue'
// Main page instance
const mainpage_inst = new createApp({
  render: () => h(MainPage),
}).$mount('#main-page')
```

Comment: Thank for the answer and help. 
Could you also add how to pass props on this instantiation, in contrast to the old way I was using ( where I was writing props:['data'] and was working?

Comment: You can pass the props using the 2nd parameter to createApp, ie `createApp({render...etc},{myProp:'abc'})` This is somewhere in the [docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/global-api.html#createapp)